# Script for hiding navbar...not on top, neither on bottom of scroll

Tags: javascript, html, css

Im a graphic designer with a little knowledge of code... but this is driving me nuts...

I got a classic navigation bar thats hidden unless user scrolls a little bit down. I got this action with javascript. OK.

But I want this happens (the action of showing navigation bar) only on the middle of every page. Like 100px away from top and 100px away from bottom of the scroll. The reason is I got breadcrumbs on top and footer on bottom of the page, I dont need the navbar there.

I tried my best to mix what I got (the navbar) with some scroll detectors, or reading bars that get scroll position... but was impossible to get something work...

¿any help please?

My code is this right now, only the navbar (improvements welcome too...heheh):

```
    var prevScrollpos = window.pageYOffset;
window.onscroll = function() {
  var currentScrollPos = window.pageYOffset;
  if (prevScrollpos > currentScrollPos) {
    document.getElementById("navbar").style.bottom = "0";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("navbar").style.bottom = "-100px";
  }
  prevScrollpos = currentScrollPos;
}
```

Comment: what the heck does this mean: "But I want this happens only on the middle of every page. Like 100px away from top and 100px away from bottom of scroll."

Comment: sorry I thought I was clear. I want "the action of showing the navigation bar" only on the middle of the scroll. 

If user is on top of the scroll, top of the site dont want the navbar.
If user is on the bottom of the scroll, on the end of the page I dont need navbar.

Just want the navbar to show when user is on the middle of the page, like 100px away from top and 100px away from bottom of scroll

Comment: @DCR it's quite clear what he means. He wants the navbar to appear when the user scrolls further than 100px down, and disappear when the user is 100px from the bottom of the page. Am I correct?

Comment: @HarleySwift totally correct! :)

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you correctly, I believe you want something like this:

```
    window.onscroll = () => { 
        const scrollPos = window.scrollY; 
        const offset = 100; const targetEl = document.body; //Adjust to preference 
        if(scrollPos > offset && (targetEl.scrollHeight - window.innerHeight - scrollY) > offset )
            console.log('shownavbar')
        else
            console.log('hidenavbar')
    }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Nour Ashraf!   :)

Your code is perfect but all together is not working much fine... I put back color change just to see easy if its working.

`var prevScrollpos = window.pageYOffset;

  window.onscroll = () => { 
    const scrollPos = window.scrollY; 
    const offset = 100; const targetEl = document.body; //Adjust to preference 
    if(prevScrollpos > scrollPos && scrollPos > offset && (targetEl.scrollHeight - window.innerHeight - scrollY) > offset)
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "green";
    else
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "red";
}`

Comment: The Navigation bar only shows when user scrolls down a little bit. So "prevScrollpos" helps with that. The initial code is not mine... I took it from an hide/show navigation bar on scroll example.

Answer (score 0):

Got it thanks to @NourAshraf. I did some changes with the code I got before and yours. Now works perfect!

Just if anyone need it finally is something like this. To check it easier I put to change the body colour to green (when the navigation bar should show) and red (when should not appear).

```
var prevScrollpos = window.pageYOffset;
window.onscroll = function() {
  var currentScrollPos = window.pageYOffset;
  var offset = 500; const targetEl = document.body; //Adjust to preference 

  if (prevScrollpos > currentScrollPos && currentScrollPos > offset && (targetEl.scrollHeight - window.innerHeight - scrollY) > offset) {
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "green";
  } else {
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "red";
  }
  prevScrollpos = currentScrollPos;
}
```